# regex conditional extract in python-re

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract the SQLCODE which typically is 4 integers from error text like below :

```
1. SQLSTATE: 22018, SQLCODE: 3535.
2. SQLSTATE: 40001, SQLCODE: 2631 Session Id           629709103
3. SQLSTATE: 40001, SQLCODE: 2631                Session Id  594700603
4. SQLSTATE: T7547, SQLCODE:   754Session Id613234380
```

I have below pattern matching regex for the same currently. However, there is aedge case like 4 which is failing.

```
error_cd = re.findall(r'SQLCODE:\s([^.,\s]+)', err_log)
```

If there are no 4 integers after SQLCODE, i would like to extract the SQLSTATE text after the letter 'T'

Expected Output :

```
1. 3535
2. 2631
3. 2631
4. 7547
```

Any suggestions on how to achieve this is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Why not use `SQLCODE:\s*(\d+)`? See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/OS0fAG/1).

Comment: I think your condition cannot be represented as a regular expression, I think it requires a more powerful computational model (I'm talking about what's taught in a computer-science course on computational models). It appears that you will have to analyze your string in two passes - the first one will check whether the SQLCODE is valid, and the other one will extract the chosen field, depending on the result of the first pass

Comment: @SomethingSomething can be done in pure regex with lookahead/behind. Check my updated solution.

Comment: @StevenMoseley Nice. I've just seen your nice answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could probably be done purely in regex, using a lookahead/lookbehind to handle the conditional extraction, but that could get really messy.

**SOLUTION 1: Pure Regex:**

EDIT: Here's the pure regex solution... simpler than I thought it would be (though definitely more error-prone than the mixed approach... would need some additional logic to make it more robust):

```
re.findall(r'((?:(?<=SQLSTATE: T)(?![0-9]{4}, SQLCODE: [0-9]{4})[0-9]{4})|(?:(?<=SQLCODE: )[0-9]{4}))', err_log)
```

**SOLUTION 2: Regex and Python:**

The following solution uses regex to pull both the SQLSTATE and SQLCODE values, and uses a list comprehension to do the conditional extraction:

```
err_log = '''
1. SQLSTATE: 22018, SQLCODE: 3535.
2. SQLSTATE: 40001, SQLCODE: 2631 Session Id           629709103
3. SQLSTATE: 40001, SQLCODE: 2631                Session Id  594700603
4. SQLSTATE: T7547, SQLCODE:   754Session Id613234380
'''

error_st_cd = re.findall(r'SQLSTATE: +T([0-9]+), SQLCODE: +([0-9]{4})?', err_log)
error_cd = [codes[1] or codes[0] for codes in error_st_cd]

for i, cd in enumerate(error_cd):
    print(f'{i+1}. {cd}')
```

Output:

> 1. 3535
> 2. 2631
> 3. 2631
> 4. 7547

Comment: Does your regex solution assume that if SQLCODE is invalid then SQLSTATE must start with a T?

Comment: Actually, does your regex solution assume that if SQLSTATE starts with a T then SQLCODE must be invalid? So SQLSTATE is automatically chosen if it starts with a T?

Comment: @SomethingSomething Yeah, the regex solution is looking for the `T\d{4}` first. A more robust solution would add an additional lookahead in the first non-matching group to check the second condition first, then strip the T out with a lookbehind. That was the type of solution that I said could get messy. But this solution is functional given the data the OP provided.

Comment: So the condition here is different from what was asked in the question. The question asked to extract SQLSTATE only if SQLCODE is invalid. I cannot imagine the DFA/state-machine that would accept such an expression, but maybe I should think more...

Comment: If there is more than one occurence of space after SQLCODE: , Regex above seems to be breaking. Sorry, for missing out the test case earlier. 

SQLSTATE: 40001, SQLCODE:   2631

Comment: @SomethingSomething Updated the answer to add the lookahead test per the OP's request.

Comment: @pats4u I updated the second answer to handle variable spaces. Lookahead/behind logic only supports fixed-width tests, unfortnately, so the pure regex fails for that new requirement.

Answer (score 1):

A regex approach might indeed be easier, but in any case, here's an approach w/o use of regex:

```py
test_string = """
1. SQLSTATE: 22018, SQLCODE: 3535.
2. SQLSTATE: 40001, SQLCODE: 2631 Session Id           629709103
3. SQLSTATE: 40001, SQLCODE: 2631                Session Id  594700603
4. SQLSTATE: T7547, SQLCODE:   754Session Id613234380
""".strip()


def process_lines(s: str):
    for line in s.split('\n'):
        sql_code = ''.join(take_nums(line.split('SQLCODE: ', 1)[-1]))
        if len(sql_code) == 4:
            yield sql_code
        else:
            sql_state = ''.join(take_nums(line.split('SQLSTATE: ', 1)[-1][1:]))
            yield sql_state


def take_nums(s: str):
    """take from string only while we get space or numeric chars"""
    for c in s:
        if c.isnumeric():
            yield c
        elif not c.isspace():
            break


for i, line in enumerate(process_lines(test_string), 1):
    print(f'{i}. {line!r}')
```

Result:

```
1. '3535'
2. '2631'
3. '2631'
4. '7547'
```